Flagging error (resulting out of a HTTP ERROR 500)?
There seems to be something wrong with the flagging.
When trying to flag this question I got an error. Reloading the page didn’t fix the issue (so it’s not a browser caching problem).

When I click either flag or close and submit that with an according close reason, the error shown in the screenshot pops up. Reloading the page shows the close/flag votes are counted dispite the error message.
Looking at the network infos, it shows the error is the result of a HTTP ERROR CODE 500.
As the next screenshot shows, I was able to increase that counter… that’s 9 x one of my votes there! (Reloading the page indicates the server increased the according counter.) 

Funny enough, the question is still open after it got 9 close-votes and flags… from a moderator. 
Since SE just recently switched to HTTPS, I’m assuming this is a server-side problem which might be related to that. If it isn’t, another server-side problem might need a fix.
Note that the problem only occurs with this “migrated” question. A few minutes before, I was able to flag Q 43123 as a duplicate without any issues.
Is the problem known already? If not, please regard this to be a bug report.

Also note that this question has been migrated from Security SE after the migration of Security SE to HTTPS. It may even have been created after the migration to HTTPS there.

I assume so as it’s (as I noted) only the migrated Q hitting this “can’t be closed” glitch. Hope the network profiling screeny showing what link runs into a 500 helps them track things down.

@sejpm Can you try to flag that one as “primarily opinion based” to see if you can reproduce my findings? When the error message pops up, reload the page and you should see a counter increase while Q is still open. If, it would prove/clarify it’s not a mod-only issue.

I VTC'ed it and got the same pop-up as you did and the Q is still open and it now allows me to retract my VTC meaning it has been recorded.

@SEJPM Thanks for confirming.

This bug (later reported on Meta Stack Overflow) has been fixed. I've successfully closed the question linked above by casting a ninth close vote. If any other questions were affected here, casting another close vote should also take care of them.
